# Failed to confirm email via integration tests (rspec/email-spec/capybara/devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I've been trying to simulate devise's confirmation through integration tests, but whenever I try to simulate clicking the confirmation link(i.e., from an email message), no confirmation was done, even though the email was successfully sent.

**tests:(registration done earlier, and is successful)**

```
  open_email user[:email]
  #Simulate confirmation
  click_first_link_in_email#Only one link in the email message i.e. confirmation link
  sleep 0.2
  expect(new_user.confirmed?).to eq true# FAILS
```

**..Results in:**

```
 Failure/Error: expect(new_user.confirmed?).to eq true

   expected: true
        got: false

   (compared using ==)
```

Even though the email was sent and the confirmation process is actually working outside the tests, why's the confirmation process not being performed in that snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is the time delay at click taking effect.

To fix, do not use `sleep` at first.

Then, test it in UI way, aka, do not expect user to have something. Instead, expect UI to have something.

```
click_first_link_in_email
expect(page).to have_content(/confirmed/)
```

If you really need to test `user`, try `reload`, but still should after UI thing - to have the wait effect.

```
click_first_link_in_email
expect(page).to have_content(/confirmed/)
user.reload
expect(user).to be_confirmed
```

Comment: I needed to test the object itself to make sure Devise is working properly(it broke once after an update). Anyway, The second solution worked. Thank you.